# How do I enable audio on a Lenovo Yoga Slim 714ARE05 using Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: 20.10

I've recently installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop with a Ryzen 4500u and integrated graphics. Everything works great (even suspend) except for audio. I'm on 20.10 with the 5.8 kernel. I've tried quite some things and throwing this in the terminal fixes it:

```
apt install --reinstall alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio linux-sound-base libasound2
```

However, a reboot results in the same problem: only "dummy output" is available. Does anyone know how I can fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I have same machine. But Intel CPU. I fix the problem installing firmware intel.
Can you post the result to this command?

```
dmesg | grep -C1 -E 'ALSA|HDA|sof|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel'
```